# Powerpoint chart data not saved

Tags: c#, office-interop

I've some office automation in c# to change slides in powerpoint.

Since some windows updates (didn't find out witch one yet), the changed chart data in the included excel, won't be saved.

It seems fine the saved powerpoint file, but, when tried to edit chart data, changes to the old values.

Does anyone have the same behavior?

my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace PowerpointAutomation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "pptx|*.pptx";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("changing chart data");

                string m_filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(m_filename);
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(m_filename);

                PowerPoint.Application objApp = new PowerPoint.Application();
                PowerPoint.Presentations objPresSet = objApp.Presentations;
                PowerPoint._Presentation objPres = objPresSet.Open(m_filename, MsoTriState./*msoTrue*/msoFalse, MsoTriState./*msoTrue*/msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                PowerPoint.Slides objSlides = objPres.Slides;
                foreach (PowerPoint._Slide objSlide in objSlides)
                {
                    PowerPoint.Shapes objShapes = objSlide.Shapes;
                    foreach (PowerPoint.Shape objShape in objShapes)
                    {
                        switch (objShape.Type)
                        {
                            case MsoShapeType.msoChart:
                                if (objShape.HasChart == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                                {
                                    PowerPoint.Chart mychart = objShape.Chart;
                                    PowerPoint.ChartData mydata = mychart.ChartData;
                                    mydata.Activate();
                                    ((Excel.Workbook)mydata.Workbook).Application.Visible = false;
                                    Excel.Workbook mywkb = mydata.Workbook as Excel.Workbook;
                                    Excel._Worksheet mysheet = (Excel._Worksheet)mywkb.Worksheets[1];
                                    Excel.Range usedRange = mysheet.UsedRange;
                                    string address = usedRange.Address;
                                    
                                    usedRange.Clear();

                                    //
                                    Excel::Range newCellsRange = mysheet.Cells;
                                    int axisCategories = 10;
                                    int serieCount = 1;
                                    int i = 0;
                                    for (i = 1; i <= axisCategories; i++)
                                    {
                                        newCellsRange.set_Item(1, i + 1, string.Format("cat{0}", i - 1));
                                    }
                                    for (i = 1; i <= serieCount; i++)
                                    {
                                        newCellsRange.set_Item(i + 1, 1, string.Format("serie{0}", i));
                                    }
                                    Random random = new Random(15);
                                    for (int r = 1; r <= serieCount; r++)
                                    {
                                        for (int c = 1; c <= axisCategories; c++)
                                        {
                                            newCellsRange.set_Item(r + 1, c + 1, random.Next(10, 1000));
                                        }
                                    }

                                    usedRange = mysheet.UsedRange;
                                    string sAddress = "=Sheet1!";
                                    sAddress += usedRange.Address;
                                    mychart.SetSourceData(sAddress);
                                    //just to make sure that is changed
                                    string excelFileSaved = fullPath.Replace(fileName+".pptx", "changedexcel.xlsx");
                                    mywkb.SaveCopyAs(@excelFileSaved);
                                    mywkb.RefreshAll();
                                    mychart.Refresh();
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                string newFileName = fileName + "_NEW";
                string newFullPath = fullPath.Replace(fileName, newFileName);
                objPres.SaveAs(@newFullPath, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
                
                MessageBox.Show("saved");

                objPres.Close();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objPres);
                objPres = null;
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objApp);
                objApp = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67933971/problem-with-generated-powerpoint-presentation-charts-in-c-sharp-with-office-int/68102044#68102044

Answer (score 0):

it seems that no one except 'mirco' works with Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.
problem solved